# PHP not executing the same function a second time

Tags: php

I have a function that I call using `Config::save('key', $value);`

```
public static function save($params, $value)
{
    $parts = explode('.', $params);
    $count = count($parts);


    $mainFile = PANEL_PATH.'/conf.php';
    $mainConfig = include $mainFile;

    if($count == 1)
    {
        if(isset($mainConfig[$parts[0]]))
        {
            $mainConfig[$parts[0]] = $value;
        }
    }
    elseif($count == 2)
    {
        if(isset($mainConfig[$parts[0]][$parts[1]]))
        {
            $mainConfig[$parts[0]][$parts[1]] = $value;
        }
    }
    elseif($count == 3)
    {
        if(isset($mainConfig[$parts[0]][$parts[1]][$parts[2]]))
        {
            $mainConfig[$parts[0]][$parts[1]][$parts[2]] = $value;
        }
    }
    elseif($count == 4)
    {
        if(isset($mainConfig[$parts[0]][$parts[1]][$parts[2]][$parts[3]]))
        {
            $mainConfig[$parts[0]][$parts[1]][$parts[2]][$parts[3]] = $value;
        }
    }

    ob_start();
    echo var_export($mainConfig);
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $content = str_replace("  ", "\t", $content);
    $content = str_replace("\n\tarray (", "array(", $content);
    $content = str_replace("\n\t\tarray (", "array(", $content);
    $content = str_replace("\n\t\t\tarray (", "array(", $content);
    $mainFileHandler = fopen($mainFile, 'w+');
    $mainFileWrite = fwrite($mainFileHandler, "<?php\n\nreturn " . $content . ";");

    if($mainFileWrite > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {               
        return false;
    }

    fclose($mainFileHandler);

}
```

And the conf.php file looks like this:

```
<?php

return array (
    'name' => '<NAME>',
    'license' => '<LICENSE>',
    'url' => '<URL>',
    'usage_id' => '<USAGE_ID>',
    'installed' => '<INSTALLED>'
);
```

So when I do this statement

```
if (Config::save('usage_id', 'USAGE_ID') && Config::save('license', 'LICENSE'))
{
    echo "Reset License";
}
```

It only resets the `license` variable, it seems like it skips over the first one. Is there something wrong with the code that's making it act like this?

If anymore code is needed let me know and I'll be glad to provide it.

Comment: What return do you get when you do a var_dump of only the first call (Config::save('usage_id', 'USAGE_ID')) , and only the second call (Config::save('license', 'LICENSE'))? Does it update now?

Comment: `bool(true) bool(true)` is the result. and it still doesn't update both, only one.